# In CSS, how to make the colored background be at least 50% of pagewidth and at most 90%, and as wide as necessary?

Tags: css, background, styles, width

In CSS, how to make the colored background be at least 50% of pagewidth and at most 90%, and as wide as necessary?

```
<pre><code> .....................
adsfdasgsfdgsfdgfsdgdsfg
adgsfdgfsdgsfd
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTML

```
<pre class="somebackground"><code>...</code></pre>
```

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.somebackground {
 background:red;
 display:inline-block; /* Changes block elements to only be 50% */
 min-width:50%;
 max-width:90%;
}
</style>
```

See [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DvdQ9/).

Comment: Could you please explain a little what does the `display:inline-block;` actually do?

Comment: Can it be achieved without using the `.somebackground` class?  The element needs to have exactly `<pre><code>... content ...</code></pre>`.

Comment: @user001, `display:inline-block` sets the element to `inline-block` instead of `block` to cause it *not* to stretch to 100% width. Otherwise, the width of the element will always be set to whatever `width` or `max-width` is set to. And yes, you *can* do it without the class (use `pre` instead), but it's not recommended for forward-compatibility reasons. For example, you may want to use the `pre` element for something else as well, later on, but will be stuck with these styles for it. So, if you opt to skip the class, be sure to specify the hierarchy as well as you can (e.g. `#article pre`).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp) and [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp).

So you could set min-width to 50% and max-width to 90%.

That way your element will always be between 50 and 90% inclusive.